# Find MAX, AVG between every current and previous row BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 150.000 rows containing DateTime and Speed column. Timestamp difference between rows is 10 seconds. I want to calculate MAX and AVG of Speed column for each 20 second segment (2x 10 sec), so basically compare each current row with its previous row and calculate MAX and AVG of Speed column.

Expected result:

```
DateTime                  Speed   MAXspeed   AVGspeed
2019-03-21 10:58:34 UTC     52                 
2019-03-21 10:58:44 UTC     50       52          51
2019-03-21 10:58:54 UTC     55       55          52.5
2019-03-21 10:59:04 UTC     60       60          57.5
2019-03-21 10:59:14 UTC     65       65          62.5
2019-03-21 10:59:24 UTC     63       65          64
2019-03-21 10:59:34 UTC     50       63          56.5
2019-03-21 10:59:44 UTC     50       50          50
2019-03-21 10:59:54 UTC     50       50          50
...
```

I tried with query below but it is obviously wrong:

```
select *,
      MAX(SpeedGearbox_km_h, LAG(SpeedGearbox_km_h) over (order by DateTime)) as Maxspeeg,
      AVG(SpeedGearbox_km_h, LAG(SpeedGearbox_km_h) over (order by DateTime)) as AVGspeed,
    from `xx.yy` 
    group by 1,2
    order by DateTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_window_spec) in your queries:

```
SELECT *,
  MAX(SpeedGearbox_km_h) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as MAXspeed,
  AVG(SpeedGearbox_km_h) OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as AVGspeed
FROM `xx.yy` 
ORDER BY DateTime
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got this error message: ORDER BY key must be numeric in a RANGE-based window with OFFSET PRECEDING or OFFSET FOLLOWING boundaries, but has type TIMESTAMP at [2:32]

Comment: I got it. I needed to change RANGE to ROWS and it worked!

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. :)